# TS typeof in constructor parameter loses type and VSCode auto-complete

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In the following TypeScript code when declaring the parameter `blobServiceClient` as `typeof BlobServiceClient`, `blobServiceClient` loses its type and is again of type "`any`" and no longer works with intellisense in VSCode (auto-complete). BlobServiceClient however is still of the correct type and works with intellisense in VSCode.

```
let { BlobServiceClient } = require( '@azure/storage-blob');

export class BlobStorageManager implements IBlobStorageManager {
    constructor(private blobServiceClient: typeof BlobServiceClient) {
        this.blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript you typically want to import packages via the `import` keyword.

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob'
```

Which should also fetch the right types along with it. Typescript has a harder time with figuring out the types of dynamic `require` statements.

Change that to import seems to

[Playground with fix](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=1&ssc=56&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQDYQEYGUCmUBuwAxjgMKrA4B28AvnAGZQQhwDkAAgIYBeArlBwB6AM4xoXAOY4AtBnQY2AWABQq4DTwMuJOAEk0mLOKhScAWS5UzURLVWqcAD0iw4RVFxEiUC4xOlLa2lbUDBUHBBqGB8DPxMzIJtEVTg09wgqMSg+IhMACjAoYHwuGBw4eSM8QhJyShoALjgYAE8wHAgGX2qCYjIKaIBKFJV08ZaAC2ARADoq7Br++ui4AF5KvyW6wZoAblT0+xVjoA)

---

Update:

> However, when I call `this.blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName)` in another function `this.blobServiceClient` is again of type any.

I'm guessing you want:

```
    constructor(private blobServiceClient: BlobServiceClient) {
        this.blobServiceClient = blobServiceClient;
    }
```

Note that the `typeof` was removed.  When you have a class in typescript, the class itself is used as the type of instances, and `typeof SomeClass` is used for the type of the constructor of that class.

So if you are expecting the constructor to receive an instance of `BlobServiceClient` then you should remove the `typeof`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=11&ssc=52&pln=11&pc=65#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgIQDYQEYGUCmUBuwAxjgMKrA4B28AvnAGZQQhwDkAAgIYBeArlBwB6AM4xoXAOY4AtBnQY2AWABQq4DTwMuJOAEk0mLOKhScAWS5UzURLVWqcAD0iw4RVFxEiUC4xOlLa2lbUDBUHBBqGB8DPxMzIJtEVTg09wgqMSg+IhMACjAoYHwuGBw4eSM8QhJyShoALl9qgmIyCmiAShSVdP64GAALYBEAOirsGvb66LgAXkq-abrOmgBuVPT7PvSttIYICHyehH2B4dGJ5bbVhpgx6RhSTJguDTxZmny2Ilf3qh4AByXCibC65x2OyAA)

Comment: Cool, that works for the constructor. However, when I call this.blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName) in another function this.blobServiceClient is again of type any.

Comment: The following function signature does not keep this.blobServiceClient's type -> public myFunction = async function (task: any, containerName: string) : Promise<boolean> / this one does ->
public async myFunction (task: any, containerName: string) : Promise<boolean>

Comment: See my update on my answer.